# Redirect a url to www with haproxy getting too many redirects

Tags: haproxy

I have an haproxy that I want to reroute only one url from test.ai to www.test.ai

`redirect prefix https://www.test.ai code 301 if { hdr(host) -i test.ai}`

But for some reason I get the `test.ai redirected you too many times.`

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a redirect set somewhere else. If you're using Wordpress as a backend. You need to set your site URL and home.

```
define( 'WP_HOME' , 'https://test.ai');
define( 'WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME . '/');
```

Then you'll need to add:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Finally be sure this is at the bottom...

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Otherwise, you may have a redirect or rewrite in your apache/nginx setup